# GDB Report (With list and frame commands) does not list line numbers

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, gdb

I am using gdb to figure out where I am getting a segfault in my program. However, my GDB report does not specify the line number, it just names the functions.

```
root@brute-force-compute:~# gcc -g -pthread program.c -o program -lmysqlclient
root@brute-force-compute:~# gdb program


(gdb) run --journal --day "Tuesday" --job "iOS" --client "SEAS"
Starting program: /root/serapis --journal --day "Tuesday" --job "iOS" --client "SEAS"
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:296
296 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) list
291 in ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S
```

EDIT: with compiling with `-g` flag

```
gcc program.c -o program -g -lmysqlclient -l pthread
gdb program
(gdb) run --journal --day "Tuesday" --job "iOS" --client "SEAS"
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:296
296 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) list
291 in ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S
(gdb) frame
#0  __strcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:296
296 in ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S
```

First attempt:

```
gcc program.c -o program -lmysqlclient -l pthread
gdb program 
(gdb) run --journal --day "Tuesday" --job "iOS" --client "SEAS"
Starting program: root/program --day "Tuesday" --job "iOS" --client "SEAS"
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:296
296 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) where
#0  __strcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:296
#1  0x0000000000402c69 in init_journal ()
#2  0x00000000004086d4 in main ()
(gdb)list
291 in ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S
(gdb) frame
#0  __strcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:296
296 in ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S
(gdb) backtrace
#0  __strcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:296
#1  0x0000000000402c69 in init_journal ()
#2  0x00000000004086d4 in main ()
```

In `main`, I do:

```
if(strcmp(argv[1], "--journal") == 0){
        printf("\nInitializing single integral machine..\n\n");
        char * template = argv[2];
        init_journal(day, job, client);
    }
```

Where day, job, client are each set earlier in `main` like so:

```
   if(strcmp(argv[i], "--day") == 0){
        day = argv[++i];
   }
```

I looked at different posts and I saw here that I should change how I put in my command line arguments in gdb:

```
run $(--journal --day "Tuesday" --job "iOS" --client "SEAS")
```

Then I get the report:

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcmp_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S:31
31  ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.
(gdb) list
26  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S
(gdb) frame
#0  __strcmp_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S:31
31  in ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse2-unaligned.S
```

Comment: compile with -g flag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> gcc program.c -o program -lmysqlclient -l pthread

This command builds your program *without* debug info. It's also incorrect in subtle other ways.

You want:

```
gcc -g -pthread program.c -o program -lmysqlclient
```

> I looked at different posts and I saw here that I should change how I put in my command line arguments in gdb:
>
> `run $(--journal --day "Tuesday" --job "iOS" --client "SEAS")`

That is *completely* bogus command line. You should *not* do that.

Comment: when I compiled with that line, I still didn't get any debug info..?

Comment: @Matt You are likely mistaken. Show us output from `where` on a program compiled with `-g`.